# Factorize product of matrices without actually computing the product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices

I have a a system of equations

$$
(B^TB + C)x = B^Tb
$$

Here, $B$ is a very large, dense matrix and $C$ is a very sparse symmetric matrix. Computing $B^TB$ is infeasible (although computing $BB^T$ would be sometimes feasible).

I'm running into issues finding $x$ with an iterative solver without preconditioning. I would like to find a factorization of $(B^TB + C)$ without computing the resulting matrix first. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can implement a Krylov solver with lazy evaluation of the matrix-vector operations, but at the cost of needing some more advanced data structures keeping track of the order of addition and multiplication with matrices and possibly needing to store several sub-results as vectors for the different terms.

Comment: Basically in each Krylov iteration if you are to multiply with $M_1M_2\cdots M_n$ from the left, keep track of the order and just, first multiply vector by $M_n$, store result, multiply vector with $M_{n-1}$, store results and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe you are speaking to solving the system without forming the left hand side. I am currently doing this with an iterative solver. However, it takes too long. I would like to form a preconditioner without forming the left hand side in order to reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: Yes, you don't even need to form the left hand side as a matrix, you can just figure out the order of matrix-vector operations to calculate and then accumulate them. Doing so also benefits from parallell processing capabilities, but at the cost of needing to store more vectors in the iteration. This allows you to for example do an FFT as a matrix product expressing fourier domain constraints without having to accumulate the DFT matrix.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it with a preconditioner. Maybe one can precondition different terms separately.

Comment: Preconditioners are just a matrix multiplication from the left on the left hand side, right? So we can choose to either just append them to the "instruction list" (last multiplication) for all terms in the left hand side. Or if practically feasible to multiply them in onto the leftmost matrix in the lhs before starting the iteration procedure.

Comment: Is $\rm B$ tall? Is computing $\rm B^\top B$ feasible? Is $\rm C$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. Updated post.

Comment: If $B$ is $m\times n$, left hand side has $m$ rows, right hand side has $n$ rows? Is there a mistake?

Comment: You are correct. I made a mistake. Updated post.